# 'FloatingLabel' is not exported from 'react-bootstrap'

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I keep trying to import FloatingLabel from react-bootstrap as specified in the bootstrap docs. However, everytime I try it tells me FloatingLabel is not exported from react-bootstrap while in the docs it says 'import FloatingLabel from 'react-bootstrap/FloatingLabel'

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I used:

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap@5.0.2
```

instead of:

```
npm install react-bootstrap@next bootstrap@5.0.2
```

And installed 1.6.1 version instead of 2.0.0 beta. The 'FloatingLabel' component is only avaliable in bootstrap 5 that is used in 2.0 version.